# Cannot umount device is busy

Tags: redhat, rhel6

**Situation**

I am running a RHEL server via a VM on my laptop.  I have a win7 desktop sharing out a folder and the VM on my laptop running RHEL6 has a CIFS windows mount at `\mnt\win`  When I go to unmount the device I get a `device is busy` message.  So I went to my laptop and check to see if there were any users connected to the share, since it listed none I turned off sharing.  I went back to my RHEL instance and attempted another `umount \mnt\win` but received the same error.

**Question**

What are other alternatives to unmounting a shared drive?

Comment: `lsof | grep '/mnt/win'`?

Comment: @quanta  Nothing...I am ready to just force this thing to shutdown...with the power button..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
umount -lf /mnt/win
```

If /mnt/win is not being used, umount will wait until it can unmount it.

Comment: Also, if you are in the mounted directory that's considered to be "in use."  Change directory to outside the mounted path.

Comment: It never unmounts just sits there forever. @AaronCopley I have tried that as well